# Set TinkerPop Configurations within Docker Image

Tags: docker, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I'm using a local implementation of TinkerPop with docker image tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.1 in order to locally interact with the graph database in nodeJs.

I need to set the IDManager to ANY so that it can accept string values for custom vertex IDs (Right now it's only working with numeric types).

I know that I need to set the configuration of TinkerGraph gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager, but I'm not sure how in my docker-compose file, I can have it initialize with the correct configurations.
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration_4

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When you launch the container using a command such as

```
 docker run --rm -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-server
```

You can optionally pass in the path to a YAML configuration file. Which would look like this:

```
docker run --rm -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-server conf/gremlin-server.yaml
```

That file is located inside the container in the `opt/gremlin-server/conf` folder. One option is to `docker exec` into the running container and edit the YAML and properties files and then create a new image from the modified one. You could also use `docker cp` to replace those files. While this will work, the downside is that you will have to do this each time you pull a newer version of the Gremlin Server image.

What you can try instead is to mount a local file system volume as part the `docker` command containing a YAML file that points to your own properties file in which you can add the ID manager lines:

```
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=ANY
gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager=ANY
```

That `docker` command will be something like this:

```
docker run --rm -p 8182:8182 -v $(pwd):/opt/gremlin-server/conf tinkerpop/gremlin-server conf/myfile.yaml
```

However, this may not work as the Gremlin Server startup script runs a `sed` command that creates a modified version of the YAML file and that requires write permissions to your local disk (this can be worked around as explained below). As a side note, that is done to fix up issues with IP addresses. The file permissions and user permissions need to be such that that `sed` command is able to run.

To work around `docker` now needing to have the ability to edit files on your local disk (rather than in the container's own ephemeral storage), at least on Linux systems, you can try using the `--user` parameter as shown below.

```
docker run --rm -p 8182:8182 --user $(id -u):$(id -g)  -v $(pwd):/opt/gremlin-server/conf tinkerpop/gremlin-server conf/myfile.yaml
```

Note that for this to work, any files that Gremlin Server expects to read from the `conf` folder as part of its bootstrap process will now need to exist on your local disk, as we have re-mapped where the `conf` folder is. The files read during startup include the `log4j-server.properties` file and any scripts and properties files referenced by your YAML file. You can copy these files from the container itself (via `docker exec` or `docker cp`) or the Apache TinkerPop Github repo.